# Define type by string

Tags: typescript, webpack

I saw below evaluation in some external sources (that I want to use in my project):

```js
const INIT: 'jsonforms/INIT' = 'jsonforms/INIT'
```

1. What does this mean, defining type by a string `INIT: 'jsonforms/INIT'`? How can a string (`'jsonforms/INIT'`) be a type?

   What is this called officially?
2. My Webpack complains about this during build and needs an additional loader:

   ```
   styleTagTransform.js:16 Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (36:17)
   File was processed with these loaders:
    * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
    * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
   You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
   | import { ErrorTranslator, Translator } from '../i18n';
   | 
   > export const INIT: 'jsonforms/INIT' = 'jsonforms/INIT';
   | export const UPDATE_CORE: 'jsonforms/UPDATE_CORE' = `jsonforms/UPDATE_CORE`;
   | export const SET_AJV: 'jsonforms/SET_AJV' = 'jsonforms/SET_AJV';
   ```

Another complaint is here:

```js
export type CoreActions =
  | InitAction
  | UpdateCoreAction
  | UpdateAction;
```

What does the above syntax mean?

```
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (65:7)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| export const REMOVE_DEFAULT_DATA = `jsonforms/REMOVE_DEFAULT_DATA`;
| 
> export type CoreActions =
|   | InitAction
|   | UpdateCoreAction
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types (and note `const INIT = 'jsonforms/INIT'` is already inferred as `const INIT: "jsonforms/INIT"`, because it's `const`).

Comment: `'jsonforms/INIT'` it is a type because is a costant and that means you cannot add any string other than `'jsonforms/INIT'` to that variable even if you doesnt provide the type explicity it will have `'jsonforms/INIT'` as a type, but in the case of a `let` you must explicity add the type `'jsonforms/INIT'` to prevent any other string value

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the missing additional loader is [ts-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-loader).

> How a string ('jsonforms/INIT') can be a type?

In TypeScript, this type is a [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).

> ```
> export type CoreActions =
> | InitAction
> | UpdateCoreAction
> | UpdateAction;
> ```
>
> What does the above syntax mean?!

This one is an [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).